# SQL Assigning Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, "`user`" and "`members`"

In "`user`" the primary key is "`user_id`" 
in "`members`" I want to make "`members_user_id`" the foreign key

so that there is a relation between the two tables. However I keep getting the following error?

Error
SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `user` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `user_id` ) REFERENCES  `Gym_System`.`members` (
`members_user_id`
) 

ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`Gym_System`.`#sql-247a_511`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-247a_511_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `members` (`members_user_id`))
```

Comment: In the future, please take a moment and try to format your question using code or the buttons on the editor, looking at the preview to see if it looks allright :)

Answer (score 0):

It the same error as here.

[Adding Foreign Key Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935003/adding-foreign-key-error/21935181)

You have missmatching row in your data. It means that sometimes user_id from user table is not matching with `Gym_System.members.members_user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> ALTER TABLE `user`     ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES
>   `Gym_System`.`members`(`embers_user_id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE
>   RESTRICT;